# Setting jquery language on all pages /or from parent page

Tags: jquery

How would you let the browser only read the jquery language file once? If I have too pages with jquery elements on them say parent and child.

Where parent requies child :

`$(document).ready(function(){
var id=$('#id').attr('value');
$('#DIV').load('child.php?id='+id);
});`

without the `src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`
on the child page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers automatically cache static resources such as javascript files. So if you have a reference to jquery on your home page and then reference it all over the other pages the browser won't fetch it from the server for child pages. It will fetch it from the cache. Also if the static resource is in the cache it might not even fetch it for the home page. That's one of the reasons why people use Content Delivery Networks for common files such as jquery. So basically you shouldn't worry too much about this: simply include jquery on all pages that require it and let the client browser handle the caching.

Comment: So I don't need to specify the language on child.php?

Comment: +1 for using Content Delivery Network - not only do you gain from caching you gain parallelism

Comment: @David, what language? Simply put `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` section of all pages that require jquery.

Comment: Thanks Aly, so I don't need to includ jquery-latest.js on child?

Comment: @David, yes you do need to include it from the very same location as your home page. The fact that you are including it from the same location (in this case Google CDN) means that the browser has already cached it and it will not send a separate HTTP request to fetch it again. But you need to include it. If you don't you will get javascript errors. It's just that the browser will get the contents from its internal cache.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time, may have sounded a little slow.., wanted to be sure. googleapis better then?

Comment: Well, it's very commonly used by many sites so chances are the client browser already has jquery in his cache and when he first visits your site he will never need to fetch it again.